# Preciso recuperar a soma dos maiores valores de cada mes

Tags: php, sql

```
SELECT SUM(valor_parametros) FROM (SELECT valor_parametros,cnpj,data_movimento FROM (SELECT valor_parametros,cnpj,data_movimento,id FROM  movimento GROUP BY MONTH(data_movimento) ORDER BY id DESC)  movimento where YEAR(data_movimento)='2020' ORDER BY id DESC) AS T GROUP BY cnpj
```

por exemplo: o cnpj 13566400130 teria que me retornar `10.2` do dia `2020-05-08` ,mas o valor de `10.20` do `2020-04-06` teria que retornar `20.40`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Para buscar os valores agrupados por mês e CNPJ e ter a soma dos valores, como você comentou em seu exemplo e na imagem, você pode utilizar a cláusula `group by` junto ao `sum`.

Por exemplo, a consulta abaixo lhe retornaria o mês (extraído da data_movimento), o CNPJ e a soma da coluna valor_parametros, agrupados pelo próprio mês e CNPJ. Desta forma, terá para cada mês cada CNPJ e a soma de valor_parametros respectivo.

```
SELECT MONTH(data_movimento), cnpj, SUM(valor_parametros) 
FROM movimento
GROUP BY MONTH(data_movimento), cnpj
```

Caso não seja exatamente esta sua dúvida, precisarei de mais detalhes para poder te ajudar!